# Adding program arguments to C

Tags: c, windows, scripting, logging, switch-statement

How can I load the batch file console to my C console?

I know in batch The command is `Showme.bat /B` and it'll load the console into whatever console you called that file from.

What would that be in `C`?

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","Showme.bat",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

Also, doing that... How could I also add additional arguments such as

`>>LogTheConsoleTo-a-File.log`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but I still cannot keep writing to the same file.

Here's what I did: `ShellExecute(NULL,"open","Showme.bat",">>consoleLog.log",NULL,SW_SHOW`);

Comment: If you answer your own question, it's nice to say *how* you figured it out so that future readers will learn something, too :)

Comment: Good idea. I added what I did

Answer (score 1):

Use the POSIX function "popen". With MSVC/MinGW you can use "_popen" instead. This give you the needed control.